# How to fix useSearchParams deopted into client-side rendering?

Tags: next.js

After updating to Next.js 14.1, I get these build messages telling me that all my pages are deopted into client-side rendering due to "useSearchParams().

Here is an example from the terminal when running next build:

```
Entire page "/404" deopted into client-side rendering due to "useSearchParams()". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering
```

I have no custom /404 page, so that is automatically generated by next, and I have search through the entire code base for useSearchParams, and I couldn't find anything

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was using "useSearchParams" in the RootLayout and I resolved these errors by using dynamic for my RootLayout

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"

function RootLayout({
  children,
}) { ... }

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(RootLayout), { ssr: false })
```